# Who is this old lady and is she some sort of cameo?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker* I was wondering who this person is? She appears near the end of the film

I looked through quite a few of the 'cameos' websites/zines, but couldn't find anything.

[image: Old lady wearing a headscarf, holding the reins of an animal's bridle. Desert-like landscape]

Comment: I assume you mean the person on the left.

Comment: I think I just decided in my head canon that she is one of the group of kids that watched Anikan build his pod racer in TPM.

Answer (score 13):

The lady in question is simply [a resident of Tatooine](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Unidentified_Tatooine_elder). She doesn't get a character name in the credits (or any of the related media) and is just described in the official [novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition) as

> "An old human woman"

and in the end credits as

> Tatooine Elder

---

There's no good indication that she's a cameo. She was played by [Ann Firbank](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ann_Firbank) who hasn't appeared in any previous *Star Wars* properties.

Comment: Given Firbank is an established actress, how are you/do they distinguish between, say, 'appearing' and 'cameo'..?

Comment: @wcullen - That's a fair question but I wouldn't say that she's famous enough to merit a "cameo" mention unless she has some other connection to the director/film series. Note that she's not *uncredited*, she has a credit but her role was so minor that it doesn't warrant a name.

Answer (score 2):

I actually think that this is a [cameo appearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cameo_appearance) (well-known, established actor) rather than a [bit part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_part) (aspiring actor, no supporting or lead roles).

Ann Firbank is a Royal Shakespeare Co veteran. She does have a (tenuous) connexion with *Star Wars* through her RSC colleagues Sebastian Shaw who played Anakin Skywalker and Ian McDiarmid who played Sheev Palpatine in *Star Wars Episode VI*.

Comment: Alec Guinness was also a RSC player. Since it was filmed in England, you can probably chuck a stone and hit an actor/actress that age that had played in the RSC ;) - tenuous connection at best, and unlikely to be a deliberate choice

Comment: @NKCampbell - Can't comment on the *nature* of the choice. Short of shooting George a quick text, all considerations of whether the choice was deliberate or not are wild speculation. You're likely right about throwing stones at RSC actors in the UK! I read that Ian McDiarmid is also an RSC vet, and was apparently as surprised to find Shaw on the set as Shaw was to find himself there. Could be that casting just had a long list of RSC actors and were like *who's next on the call list? Oh, Ann Firbank? All right, give her a ring!*

Comment: I would ask those who disagree that Ann Firbank is not an example of a cameo to direct me to how they are determining that. The definitions of a 'cameo appearance' seem to fall between "a brief appearance or voice part of a well known person in a work of the performing arts" (Wikipedia) or "a short appearance in a film or play by a well-known actor (Longman Dictionary). Some expanded discussions (e.g. Wiki) do talk about some specifics; but, none would seem to leave Firbank out. I certainly appreciate the discussion, but I think those disagreeing are using a narrow use of the term.

Comment: I really don't think she's a cameo. I just think she was hired as an actress to play a small role.

Comment: @Valorum - Possible. One thing I'm sure of: if they hired me from off the street and said "here, wear this costume and stand there holding this four eyed camel for a bit", that **wouldn't** be a cameo. That would be a random person playing a bit part. Whereas, I think a veteran actor being hired to play what would otherwise be a bit part is a cameo by definition.

Comment: @elemtilas - If you can find a better connection that just that she played with the RSC, I'd be happy to reconsider, but as has been pointed out, so have dozens of other bit parts in the Star Wars universe, largely as a consequence of the films being made (partly) in the UK.

Comment: @Valorum - Like I said earlier, the real nature of the choice is a matter of speculation on our part. I obviously  don't have any better evidence for my conclusion apart from common or accepted definitions; and I don't see any solid evidence for this being a mere bit part. So I think we're just going to remain stuck with what little we do have, and that's basically no real evidence either way.

Comment: I honestly don't beleive that "being filmed in the UK" is evidence countering the proposition that this is a cameo. Perhaps it's better evidence that this is a cameo; after all, it's not like they couldn't find an amateur actor to do a bit piece.

Comment: Ann Firbank  IS a well established/well known actress (UK film, TV, and theatre). Being 87 y/o in 2017 it seems unlikely that she was just another hire. I gave two examples of 'cameo appearance' and she meets these on all accounts. I also add that, from what I've read, a lot of what constitutes a 'cameo appearance' can have as much to do with connections on those working inside the industry as it can by way of recognition by audiences. So, even if we, as an audience, don't recognize her (or see her as famous) other audiences (e.g. UK) likely do and her connection maybe an insider connection.

Comment: @wcullen - As someone who lives in the UK, I can tell you that she's not a 'known name', nor considered in any way famous. She's just a jobbing actress

Comment: “you can probably chuck a stone and hit an actor/actress that age that had played in the RSC” — you can, and you are encouraged to whenever possible, to discourage them from spontaneously doing a monologue from _Richard III_ or something.